# How can I set circle size of the pie chart with jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I ned to set the circle size for pie chart with jqplot....I have following code snippet...

```
var plot = jQuery.jqplot ('chart', [data], 
                {                       
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                        rendererOptions: {
                            showDataLabels: true
                        },
                        pointLabels: { show: true }                          
                    }, 
                    diameter : 1,
                    legend: { 
                        show:true,
                        location: 'e',                    
                        placement: 'inside'                    
                    },
                    title: {

                        fontSize:'14px',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontFamily: 'Arial',                    
                        show: true
                    }
                }
```

is this the right way to set diameter for the circle?

Comment: remove the java tag pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be under the `seriesDefault.renderOptions.diameter`. See their documention at http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html

```
seriesDefaults: {
    rendererOptions: {
        diameter: 1, // diameter of pie, auto computed by default.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set diameter under rendererOptions.....

```
var plot = jQuery.jqplot ('chart8', [xyOrgIP], 
                {
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                        rendererOptions: {
                            showDataLabels: true,
                            diameter : 100
                        },
                        pointLabels: { show: true }

                    },                   
                    legend: { 
                        show:true,
                        location: 'e',                    
                        placement: 'inside'                    
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Traffic Analysis by Origin IP (Last 7 Days)',   // title for the plot,
                        fontSize:'14px',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontFamily: 'Arial',                    
                        show: true
                    }
                }
```