# How can I decrease the height of the PieChart Grid?

Tags: grid, jqplot, pie-chart

[PieChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgmUp.png)

How can I decrease the height of the PieChart Grid?

I'm using [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) and javascript. This is what I have:

```
function skinPie() {                

    this.cfg.grid = {
        background: '#FF0000',
        borderColor: '#FF0000',
        gridLineColor: '#F5F5F5',                   
        shadow: false                                
    };

    this.cfg.axesDefaults = {
        rendererOptions: {
            textColor:'#0c0c0c',                                                        
        }
    };

    this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
        renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        shadow: false,
        lineWidth: 1,                    
        markerOptions: {
            shadow: false,
            size: 7,
            style: 'circle',                      
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you using `R lang` ?

Comment: I tried this.cfg.axesDefaults = {
                    rendererOptions:                    
                     padding: 10                                             
              }
                }; but nothing happend, also I tried marginTop no i use primefaces

Comment: you should post your code on the question and specify the programming language

Comment: I did i use jqplot and javascript and my piecharts are with primefaces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set circle size of the pie chart with jqplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503417/how-can-i-set-circle-size-of-the-pie-chart-with-jqplot)

Comment: no i mean the grid, the background, not the circle size!

Comment: don't you define that on the `div` where the piechart is loading ? like using css to define the max-size of the `div`

Comment: the div class is jqplot-target

Comment: you mean like this? <style type="text/css">      
            .jqplot-target, .jqplot-axis {
             color: #191919;            
            }
            .jqplot-target {
             margin-bottom: 45px;
             margin-top: 50px  
            }
        </style>

Comment: Yes. That doesn't help ?

Comment: not excatly, it changes, but not how I want it

Comment: its working I put a minus before

Comment: :) I was making an example but thanks God you could solve it.

Comment: i want to decrease the height and somehow its not working like i wanted

Comment: where did you make an example, I want to decrease the grid not the cicle!

Comment: maybe i need padding-top and padding-bottom?

Comment: Well, I recommend `margin-top`. And may also use `!important` if there is another style trying to overwrite that class.

Comment: Im not sure if its called grid, but the area where the piecart is on it as you can see in the picture, I need to reduce its height!

Comment: so that the space around the piechart becomes less